# javascript - comparing values in an array of objects with a response array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm building a small app where you add up to 10 items into a "bag".

Once an item is added to a bag, it is added into a `bag []`.  Each item has an `id`.

However, I get the items from an API call, so when I get items, I want to ensure that if I have already added an item to bag, it doesn't mess with the bag state.

Here's what I'm doing when I receive items from the API:

```
items.map(i => {
  i.inBag: false
});
```

However, this will reset the `inBag` even if I've added an item into my bag.  When an item is added into a bag, the `inBag` flips to true.  But next time the API call is made, it will reset to `false`.

How can I ensure that when I receive something from the API, that I also check whether the `i.id` exists in an item in `bag[]`?

I'm afraid it will be too slow if I do it by comparing in each iteration, so I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Thanks

Comment: You could take a look at [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: That arrow function seems to be a syntax error. Did you mean `=` instead of `:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

If bag is not array of object

```
if(bag.indexOf(received_item_id)==-1)
{
    //write code to insert item into bag[]
}
```

If bag is array of object

```
if(JSON.stringify(bag).indexOf(JSON.stringify(object_getting_from_api))==-1)
{
    //write code to insert item into bag[]
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  But bag is an array of objects, so `[{id: 2003, name:"one"}, {id: 2004, name:"two"}]`  How to handle that?

Comment: There is also [Array#findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Answer (score 0):

Given these arrays:

```
arrayA = [{id: 2003, name:"one"}, {id: 2004, name:"two"}];
arrayB = [{id: 2003, name:"foo"}, {id: 2005, name:"three"}];
```

To add only the new `id` values, use [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
arrayA.concat(arrayB.filter( v => !arrayA.filter(e => e.id === v.id).length ));
```

Which gives:

```
[{id: 2003, name:"one"}, {id: 2004, name:"two"}, {id: 2005, name:"three"}];
```

#### UPDATE:

As suggested by [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428063/javascript-comparing-values-in-an-array-of-objects-with-a-response-array-of-ob/39429118?noredirect=1#comment66182266_39429118), this is more legible:

```
arrayA.concat(arrayB.filter( v => arrayA.every(e => e.id !== v.id) ));
```

Which means: concatenate with arrayA all elements in arrayB for which every element in arrayA holds the condition that none of its id objects are present in arrayB.

Comment: Never use `filter(…).length`. You want `some` or `every`.